# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3x+1)^{-3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can anyone think of an easy way to find the values of $x$ for which the following series converges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3x+1)^{-3n}$$

I'm thinking some convergence test (root test, perhaps?) but I'm a little rusty on these things and I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (3x+1)^{-3n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty y^n$ where $y=(3x+1)^{-3}$, which is a standard geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Write $(3x+1)^{-3n}=\bigl((3x+1)^{-3}\bigr)^n$, set $r=(3x+1)^{-3}$, and try to recognize the series as a well-known type.